# How to deal with error object passed into callback in an async remote method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I want my remote method **returns a 404 HTTP error** created by `http-errors` with the message in a remote method implemented in an async way like below.

```
const createError = require('http-errors');

Model.methodA = async (postBody, cb) => {
  const resp = await fetchData()
  if(!resp){
    return cb(createError(404, `data not found`));
  }
  return resp;
}

Model.remoteMethod(
  'methodA',
  {
    description: '',
    http: {path: '/', verb: 'post', status: 200},
    accepts: [
      {
        arg: 'postBody',
        type: 'object',
        http: {source: 'body'}
      }
    ],
    returns: {type: 'object', root: true}
  });
```

However, when I ran the code above, it always says I'm not dealing with promise rejection correctly.

```
(node:39109) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

I know I can change the way I call `fetchData()` into `fetchData().then().catch()`, and then no need to decorate my `methodA` with `async` keyword. I still think there gotta be a better way to deal with this async methodA calling though. Thanks.

Comment: `Model.methodA()` returns a promise (all `async` functions return a promise).  The caller needs to use `await` or `.then()` with that returned promise.  So, your `Model.methodA()` that both takes a callback as an argument AND returns a promise is a franken-design.  Pick one style or the other, not both.  Also, for `await` to do anything useful, `fetchData()` needs to return a promise too.

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but where should I use `.then()`, and what if I want to return a 404 error as I mentioned above. Could you please elaborate it a little bit?

Comment: Show us the code for `fetchData()` so we can see how it works (and whether it returns a promise or not).  And, show us code that calls `Model.methodA()` so we can advise how that code should work.  Right now, you have a terrible design that tries to return some errors through a callback and some through a promise.  It appears there's enough that you don't understand about the proper design that we need to see the bigger problem to make appropriate recommendations.

Comment: basically what inside `fetchData()` is a http get call using `request-promise`.

Comment: And, are you just returning the promise from `request-promise` as the return value of `fetchData()`?  I could stop asking 20 questions if you just showed us the code for both `fetchData()` and for the callers of `Model.methodA()`.  I asked for that for a reason.  We can help you massively better when we see the WHOLE context of the problem.

Comment: the reason I use `fetchData()` is that I need to do some processing work for the response from `request-promise` before it returns to `methodA()`

Answer (score 1):

First off, do not ever write code that returns some error via plain callback, the value via a resolved promise and some other errors via rejected promise.  This would be a nightmare for anyone to code with.

So, you say that `fetchData()` returns a promise from (request-promise).  Then, all you need to do is just return its promise:

```
Model.methodA = (postBody) => {
     return fetchData(...);
}
```

Unless you are going to process the result inside of methodA, there's no reason to use `await` there.  `async` functions already return a promise so you aren't gaining anything by use `await` and then just returning that value.  It's still just the resolved value of a promise returned by the function which is the same as just returning the original promise you already have.

And, the caller of `Model.methodA()` needs to use `Model.methodA().then().catch()` to get value and error or use `let val = await Model.methodA()` with a `try/catch` around it to get value and error.

Without seeing the additional code I've asked for to see the whole context of the problem, this is about the best we can advise.

Answer (score 0):

as the error says,you should think about to catch the promise rejection,but you do not wanna use `.then().catch`,may be you should think about `try ... catch`

```
Model.methodA = async (postBody, cb) => {
try{  
   const resp = await fetchData();
  }catch{
   return cb(createError(404, `data not found`));
}
  return resp;
}
```

Comment: Returning value via promise and errors via plain callback is a nightmare design.  I would not every recommend this.